# Understanding casting a type into interface via map

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am new in angular and I am trying to understand how the mapping from a response into an interface works.

I have following API response:

```
   [ {
   "id": 2,
   "name" : "Josh",
    } ];
```

and my TS interface looks like this:

```
   export interface User {
      name: string;
      id: number | null;
     }
```

I make a simple get call in the service:

```
   getUser() {
   return this.http.get<User>('http://localhost:4200/user/1').pipe(
          map((response: User) =>
          this.response = response,
          ));
      }
```

And subscribe in the component:

```
   callGetUser() {
          this.getUser().subscribe((response: User) => {
          this.user = response;
          });
   }
```

My user is also from type User:

```
   user: User;
```

That I expect is that I get a user attribute of type User. I would also expect an error if the attributes from the response are not matching the attributes from the User interface - e.g I pass an "id2"-attribute , see pics below.

This is the case is simply define an User-instance in TS:

[image]

[image]

My question is why is the mapping working even when the attributes are not matching? Should't I get an error? Is there a way to get an error if so?

Comment: What do you mean there is no error? There is error in the screenshot you posted...

Comment: Obviously the compiler will not raise an error since your code is good. At run time, if the server returns an object that does not match the expected interface, then it will map any matching properties and continue silently unless your code expects a property to be non-null and the server does not return this property. You need to verify the response shape in your code and defend against a bad response.

Comment: You already have an error... mapping can be done only for matching fields... you already have an error so you can see that type checking works... specify field i2 in your class to remove it.

Comment: Don’t forget, an interace no longer exists runtime..

Comment: @Benny : I don't get any error when I change the responseDto in the API or/and the interface in Angular. Basically, whatever I do, I get the data from the API the way it is.
What do you mean by "verify the response shape in your code?". Could you please elaborate of this a bit? If I need to do another step, why do I need the mapping at all? Thanks!

Comment: @dani_bandita (hoping I understand what you want to achieve) I mean that if for example you expect the server to return an object `{ id: string; name: string; }` you should check e.g. `if (response.id === undefined) { error handing code }`. This will handle scenarios where the server sends back e.g. `{ id2: string; name: string; }`. BTW by "shape" I mean object structure.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remember that Typescript will be compiled into Javascript before being execute.
Javascript has no kind of type checking, so when you write

```
getUser() {
   return this.http.get<User>('http://localhost:4200/user/1').pipe(
   map((response: User) =>
          this.response = response,
   ));
}
```

you're saying that you're sure that the http request will return an Object with the same structure as User.
The problem is that during runtime (when the call is actually performed), there will be no type checking, cause the browser is reading Javascript, not Typescript.
The only way you could check the consistency of an object is to check if it has all the properties.
So if User has an id and a name you could change your map like this:

```
return this.http.get<User>('http://localhost:4200/user/1').pipe(
  map((response: User) =>
      if(response.id && response.name)
          this.response = response;
      else
          console.log('This is not a user!');
  ));
}
```

Comment: Exactly. As I commented above on the question.

Comment: Thank you @Federico Galfione and @Benny! I am aware of that TS/JS difference, but was not aware that the browser does not do any type checking.